# How to search Bookmark with ctrlp in VIM

Tags: vim

With command CtrlPBookmarkDirAdd which is added sucessfully a bookmark. But I couldn't find any instruction how to list the added bookmarks like NERDTree.

Any method ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:CtrlPBookmarkDir` is *very* close to `:CtrlPBookmarkDirAdd` in `:h ctrlp`.

Comment: I did, but when I type like this :CtrlPBookmarkDir <name>, it show error trailling characters

Comment: You must hit `<CR>` to get the list.

Comment: It not return the expected bookmark instead of a whole system files. Really confusing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `:CtrlPBookmarkDir<CR>` allows you to chose your root directory from a list of bookmarks. After you have chosen  the directory you hit `<CR>` to get to the regular prompt where you can choose your file by typing a few letters. The entire point of CtrlP is to provide a common fuzzy searching interface for common situations. From that point of view, it's quite the opposite of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble that `:CtrlPBookmarkDir<CR>` shows `== NO ENTRIES ==`, although `:CtrlPBookmarkDirAdd <Dir>` finished successfully.

In my case, this was caused by permission about `$HOME./.cache/ctrlp`.
It was made with root owner.
Maybe, I used CtrlP plugin with `sudo vim` at first time.

I fixed direcotry owner and register bookmarks again, then I got proper output.